# Create a variable with only non NA values in R from multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like so:

```
name1 <- c("a", NA, "b")
name2 <- c(NA, "c", "d")

mydf <- cbind.data.frame(name1, name2)
```

I want to create a variable which takes only the non-NA values from the two columns, and in the case of both names being different and non-NA, it only keeps the first one. The result therefore should be "a", "c", "b" (keeps a from the first row, c from the second, and b from the third). Would be good if it works for more than 2 columns.

Comment: `apply(mydf, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a tidy approach, you may use `coalesce()`, where you can either specify a set of columns or use the full dataset.

I extended your example to demonstrate use of multiple columns and remaining NAs.

```r
library(tidyverse)
name1 <- c("a", NA, "b", NA, NA)
name2 <- c(NA, "c", "d", NA, NA)
name3 <- c(letters[5:8], NA)
name4 <- rep(NA, 5)

mydf <- cbind.data.frame(name1, name2, name3, name4)
mydf
#>   name1 name2 name3 name4
#> 1     a  <NA>     e    NA
#> 2  <NA>     c     f    NA
#> 3     b     d     g    NA
#> 4  <NA>  <NA>     h    NA
#> 5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    NA

mydf %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # specify columns explicitly
  mutate(new1 = coalesce(name1, name2, name3)) %>% 
  # or use all column in given order
  mutate(new2 = coalesce(!!!syms(colnames(.))))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   name1 name2 name3 name4 new1  new2 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     <NA>  e     NA    a     a    
#> 2 <NA>  c     f     NA    c     c    
#> 3 b     d     g     NA    b     b    
#> 4 <NA>  <NA>  h     NA    h     h    
#> 5 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA    <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>